# Что значит ошибка: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it

Tags: c#, unity3d

Суть кода создание нового врага по шаблону старого, после его уничтожения. Когда убиваю врага который изначально был в сцене то всё нормально, появляется следующий (его клон), но стоит убить его клона так всё  останавливается и выдаёт следующую ошибку:
`The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if it it is null or you should not destroy the object.`

Код создания нового врага:

```
public class ScenController : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField] private GameObject enemyPrefab; //Сюда помещён объект врага

    private GameObject _enemy;

   
    void Update()
    {
        if (_enemy == null)
        {
            _enemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab) as GameObject;

            _enemy.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);

            float angle = Random.Range(0, 360);
            _enemy.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 0); 
        }
    }
}
```

Код стрельбы персонажа и уничтожения врага:

```
public class RayShooter : MonoBehaviour
{

    Camera camera ;

    public Transform Pointer;

    private void Start()
    {
        camera = GetComponent<Camera>();
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }

    void OnGIU()
    {
        int size = 24;
        float posX = camera.pixelWidth / 2 - size / 4;
        float posY = camera.pixelHeight / 2 - size / 2;
        GUI.Label(new Rect(posX, posY, size, size), "*");
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector3 point = new Vector3(
            camera.pixelWidth / 2, camera.pixelHeight / 2, 0);
            Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(point);
            RaycastHit hit;
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                GameObject hitObject = hit.transform.gameObject;
                ReactiveTarget target = hitObject.GetComponent<ReactiveTarget>();
                if (target != null)
                {
                    target.ReactToHit(); // Запуск функции в скрипте реагирования врага на смерть
                    Debug.Log("Target hit");
                }
                else
                {
                    
                    StartCoroutine(SphereIndicator(hit.point)); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    private IEnumerator SphereIndicator(Vector3 pos)
    {
        GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
        sphere.transform.position = pos;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        Destroy(sphere);
    }
}
```

Движение врага

```
public class WanderingAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool _alive; //булевая переменная для определения жив или нет

    public float speed = 3.0f;

    public float obstaclrenge = 5.0f;

    private void Start()
    {
        _alive = true; // в начале всегда жив
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (_alive) // если жив то двигается
        { 

            transform.Translate(0, 0, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.SphereCast(ray, 0.75f, out hit)) //если стена впереди то поворот
        {
            if (hit.distance < obstaclrenge)
            {
                float angle = Random.Range(-110, 110);
                transform.Rotate(0, angle, 0);
            }
        }
        
    }

    public void SetAlive(bool alive) // меняем значение на false если умер
    {
        _alive = alive;
    }
}
```

Реагирование врага на смерть:

```
public class ReactiveTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public void ReactToHit()
    {
        WanderingAI behavior = GetComponent<WanderingAI>();//Компоненты из скрипта движения врага
        if (behavior != null)
        {
            behavior.SetAlive(false);//если компонентов нет то меняем на false и убиваем
        }
        StartCoroutine(Die());//запуск анимации смерти
    }

    private IEnumerator Die() // анимация смерти
    {
        this.transform.Rotate(-75, 0, 0);//кладём враг на спину типо умер

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f);// ждём секунду для драмтургии

        Destroy(this.gameObject); // уничтожение объекта
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы же понимаете, о чем написано в ошибке? `Объект типа 'GameObject' был ранее уничтожен, но вы всё еще пытаетесь к нему обращаться. Ваш скрипт должен проверять его на null, либо не нужно уничтожать этот объект.`

Answer (score 1):

Всё понятно. Я сунул в шаблон GameObject (1 скрипт 4 строка) врага через меню Hierarchy, и после уничтожал этот объект в игре в последствии теряя связь с ней(Отсюда и ошибка).

Решение: перетаскиваем объект который должен служить шаблоном из меню Hierarchy в меню Assets, и уже из меню Assets перетаскиваем в GameObject шаблона.

Спасибо aepot который пытался разобраться в каше которую я заварил.